# "..., making it / itself ideal for toddlers" in this context

Tags: pronouns, participle-clauses

A school bag commercial says:

> The bag is lightweight, making **it** ideal for toddlers.

Can I replace the **it** with **itself** as the **bag** is qualifying **itself** (*the bag)*?

Answer (score 2):

No. A bag is an inanimate object and can do nothing by itself. It cannot make itself useful. Its suitability or usefulness is by design.

The sentence is saying that a specific quality of the bag - the fact it is lightweight - is the thing that makes the bag ideal for toddlers.